# download only .csv files from external FTP server to my ftp server

Tags: php, ftp

I have a script which connects to an external ftp server and downloads the contents of a folder.

Currently it will download all files in the folder. How can I modify the below script to only download and process .csv files and ignore any other files?

My script is (which works 100%):

```
$timenow=time();
$ftp_server = "ftp.domain.com";  
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);  
$ftp_user_name = "username";  
$ftp_user_pass = "password";  
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);  
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, 'LoadsOverWB'); 
$targetnameprocesses ="LoadsOverWB-$timenow.csv";


$filename = $contents[0]; 

echo "<br><font color=blue><b>Import into LOC MySQL.....</b></font><br>";
// import file
if ((empty($filename))) { echo "$filename not existing to import.";} else {
$source = "LoadsOverWB/$filename";
 $target = fopen("$filename", "w");

$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.hulamin.co.za") or die("Could not connect");
 ftp_login($conn,"TransportLogistics","Qaz1234");

ftp_fget($conn,$target,$source,FTP_ASCII);

echo "file downloaded. <br>";
```

Thanks as always for the assistance,

Comment: $source is the file downloaded, just change that, and remove the loop

Comment: Thanks Dagon, how can I tell if $Source is a csv file or not, and if not ignore. $source is effectively the first file in the ftp list? Thanks again.

Comment: do you know the filename of the file you want?

Comment: Filename is a variable with a timestamp so script is currently looking at the first file in the list `ftp_nlist` and `$contents[0]` is the first file in that list. I just want to exclude all files that are not csv? can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ('.csv' == strtolower(substr($filename, -4))) { //Get the file }
```

Comment: Thanks, error message `: Call to undefined function lower() in...`

Comment: Sorry. It's `strtolower()` in PHP.